# jQuery Mobile checkbox + textarea

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, checkbox, textarea

I'm using a controlgroup in jQuery Mobile to position a checkbox next to a textarea.

[image]

This function checks changes in the checkbox (checked=true/false) and adds a class to strike the text in the textarea:

```
$('body').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"].todoitem', set_status_todoitem);
```

This works fine, but my problem is that when clicking on the textarea (blur/focus?) the checkbox is checked. I want to be able to edit the text in the textarea without checking the checkbox. Another issue is the fact that the focus is not set on the textarea when clicking it on a mobile device, so the keyboard does not appear.

My html markup is the following:

```
<fieldset id="todoitems" data-role="controlgroup">
    <div class="todoitem" id="id1">
        <input type="checkbox" class="todoitem" id="id1">
        <label for="id1"><textarea class="todoitem" id="id1">Item 1</textarea></label>
    </div>
    <div class="todoitem" id="id2">
        <input type="checkbox" class="todoitem" id="id2">
        <label for="id2"><textarea class="todoitem" id="id2">Item 2</textarea></label>
    </div>
    <div class="todoitem" id="id3">
        <input type="checkbox" class="todoitem" id="id3">
        <label for="id3"><textarea class="todoitem" id="id3">Item 3</textarea></label>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

The div tags are there because of the sortable function I'm using.

Comment: maybe try using a grid or table for the layout: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/b9rxzqs2/1/

Comment: Great solution, but what about "controlgroup"? I like the "grouped view".

Comment: Are you just talking about the controlgroup borders? You can style the table: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/b9rxzqs2/5/

Comment: Does this have anything to do with jquery-ui`..?